# How to return an object from a class to to the main method?

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to make a class object and pass the info in the object to the method in program class then call the method in the main method. When I run the program, it doesn't show the values that I pass in the parameters./

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CreateVsquare(4,7));
        }
        public static Vsquare CreateVsquare(int width, int length)
        {
            Vsquare rect = new Vsquare(4,7);
            rect.length = length;
            rect.width = width;
            return rect;
        }

    }
    public class Vsquare
    {
        public int length;
        public int width;
        public Vsquare(int w, int l)
        {
            l = length;
            w = width;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your expect result? When you are `Console.WriteLine(CreateVsquare(4,7));` you will call `toString` method from `Vsquare` class.

Comment: When you pass an object to `Console.WriteLine`, it's `ToString` method is implicitly called. Since you haven't overloaded that method, it will just print out the name of your type.

Comment: I'm trying to display the two values that are in the parameters

Comment: To display those values in the console:In your main create an instance of your object `Vsquare myVsquare = CreateVsquare(4,7)` then `Console.WriteLine(myVsquare.length)` and `Console.WriteLine(myVsquare.width)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. got solved now

Comment: btw. your `l = length;` in `Vsquare` should be `length = l`. Same for the width.

Comment: Just did it but it shows the same result. What's difference will it make?

Comment: I assume you want to assigne the value of `l` to `length`. But in the constructor of `Vsquare`you assign the value of `length` to `l`. It shows the same result, because in the method `CreateVsquare` you assign the values again.

Answer (score 2):

[`Console.WriteLine(object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Object_) converts the `object` parameter to a `string` by calling the `object.ToString()` method on the object. By default, [`object.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a `string` with the name of the object's type; you can override this behavior since the method is virtual, e.g.:

```
    public class Vsquare
    {
        public int length;
        public int width;
        public Vsquare(int w, int l)
        {
            l = length;
            w = width;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
           return $"{l},{w}";
        }
    }
```

(As noted in the comments for the question, the constructor's assignment statements are backward, but I haven't fixed that in this excerpt.)